# me sale error en Auto() takes no arguments osea sobre la variable lo reinicie y me sale error el programa corre bien pero al poner mi_auto = Auto()

Tags: python

```
class Auto:   # class palabra reservada y Auto nombre identificador de la clase 
    
    def ___init__(self, marca, modelo, año, color):
        self.marca = marca       # atributos
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.año = año 
        self.color = color  
        self.velocidad_actual = 0      # son todos atributos desde marca a color .
         
    
    def acelerar(self, velocidad):      # metodos
        self.velocidad_actual += velocidad
        
    def frenar(self, velocidad):    # metodos
        self.velocidad_actual -= velocidad
        
    def obtener_velocidad_actual(self):     # metodos
        return self.velocidad_actual               

mi_auto = Auto(marca= "fiat", modelo= "palio", año= "2020", color= "rojo")
```

El programa corre bien, pero cuando le doy enter me sale error, probé darle dos guiones bajos a la función init, corre, pero en la variable mi_auto me da error.

Comment: Hola, a primera vista, me parece que son dos errores diferentes. (Ayudaria mucho si se pudieran publicar). El primero parece ser justo por el tiple guion en el init (`___init__`  en vez de `__init__`). El segundo error no podria saber a que se debe porque no hay mas descripcion, Podria ser debido a que se haya llamado mal alguno metodo del objecto?

Comment: Hola Ruben, he cambiado lo de los guiones, y tu código me funciona... podrías indicar cual es el error que te arroja?.